# Error when I tried to follow the ReactJS.org documentation

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am following the instructions here:
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment.

After step 6 I am being asked to run npm start. This is the result:

[image]

This is what is inside package.json in the scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

This is my index.js file for now:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
```

Basically I just ran `npx create-react-app my-app` and tried to replace what is inside src with a .js file.

Comment: What *precisely* did you do after the npx command? What's the `git diff`, for example?

Comment: @Praveen the OP doesn't say they copied and pasted

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am sorry. Thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your first two characters in the `index.js` file are some random characters. Get rid of them. It should work. Use a proper editor that supports UTF 8 and BOM.

[image: preview]

I don't think there's anything wrong with the documentation. Also, they say:

> *We strongly recommend typing code by hand as you’re working through the tutorial and not using copy/paste. This will help you develop muscle memory and a stronger understanding.*

Not just that, the HTML might have constructed using other generators that might add non-visual contents. From the above screenshot, it's very evident that there are two non-visual contents in the start of the line. Please remove that.

Comment: Already did, typed the first line by hand: import React from 'react';...still seeing the same error

Comment: @carlospalma The problem is with the first two **invisible** characters.